# Show blank cell result if a cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I am trying to create a social media keyphrase strategy using keywords. I would like to know if Google Sheets could return a blank cell if one of the cells in the concatenate formula is blank?

Answer (score 0):

- this formula concatenates columns **A**, **B** and **C** only if all 3 cells per row are not empty:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A)*LEN(B1:B)*LEN(C1:C), A1:A&" "&B1:B&" "&C1:C, ))
  ```

  [image: 0]